# RSolr::Error::Http - 400 Bad Request - Missing solr core name in path

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, tomcat, solr

I would like to send json data from my android app to a ruby on rails webApp which uses solr search engine. But every time I send data, I get this error message :

> RSolr::Error::Http - 400 Bad Request Error: Apache Tomcat/7.0.68 (Ubuntu) - Rapport d''erreur
>
> ## Etat HTTP 400 - Missing solr core name in path
>
> **type** Rapport d''état
>
> **message** Missing solr core name in path
>
> **description** La requête envoyée par le client était syntaxiquement incorrecte.
>
> #### Apache Tomcat/7.0.68 (Ubuntu)
>
> URI: http://localhost:8080/solr/update?wt=ruby Request Headers: {"Content-Type"=>"text/xml"} Request Data: "" Backtrace: /home/wivi/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rsolr-1.1.1/lib/rsolr/client.rb:288:in `adapt_response' /home/wivi/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rsolr-1.1.1/lib/rsolr/client.rb:189:in`execute' /home/wivi/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rsolr-1.1.1/lib/rsolr/client.rb:175:in `send_and_receive' /home/wivi/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sunspot_rails-2.2.5/lib/sunspot/rails/solr_instrumentation.rb:16:in`block in send_and_receive_with_as_instrumentation' /home/wivi/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument' /home/wivi/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in`instrument' /home/wivi/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument' /home/wivi/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sunspot_rails-2.2.5/lib/sunspot/rails/solr_instrumentation.rb:15:in`send_and_receive_with_as_instrumentation' (eval):2:in `post' /home/wivi/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rsolr-1.1.1/lib/rsolr/client.rb:84:in`update' /home/wivi/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rsolr-1.1.1/lib/rsolr/client.rb:113:in `commit'

I have tried many things but without success. Is there anybody who has an idea to resolve this problem ? Thanks in advance for your help.

Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

As the error says - you're missing the core name or collection name from the Solr URL.

The core name / collection name is the part after "solr" in the URL:

```
http://../solr/collection-name
```

When setting up your Solr core/collection for indexing into, you probably used a collection or core name. This has to be provided to the ruby module you're using, either through the URL or through a specific setting (depends on the library - most just asks you to include it in the URL).

In very old versions of Solr - which only supported one set of data at a time - the URL didn't need to have a core name or collection name present, which is why you might see the old URL formats still around.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Finally, I succeeded to resolve my problem.